# How to add custom button in header.phtml which do custom functionality?

Tags: layout, header

I have created custom module and I need to add button in header.phtml which 'onclick' will call a method from my module but i'm not sure how to do this. Should I create block and template or any other way? Can you give me some tips because "View" part is still a mystery for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furoris:Create block class and template file and layout file call  this template and make header as reference block.Then on header.phtml call this block using   `getChildHtml();`

**just Like:**

```
<default><!-  call on all pages -->
<reference name="header">
<block type="yourBLockPrefix/restofblockclass" name="myblockcustom" template="mytem patefoder/mytemplate.phtml"/>
</reference>
</default>
```

**header.phtml**:

add the code `<php echo $this->getChildHtml('myblockcustom')?>`